# Deploy Node JS app onto AWS EC2 with CodeDeploy

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to deploy a very basic Node JS application onto an AWS EC2 instance with CodeDeploy. I'm running into an issue where the deployment fails because the Node JS app is already running on the port the application is running on. I'm not sure entirely how to approach this situation. The app is designed to run on port 3000. Below is the error message I get from the script that CodeDeploy is executing. I tried going into the instance and terminate the process that is running on port 3000, but it seems after terminating the process the application spins right back up. Please let me know if anything is needed to be helpful. Any advice would be appreciated.

**Error**

```
[stderr]+ return 1
[stderr]+ '[' -n 'Now using node v16.15.0 (npm v8.5.5)' ']'
[stderr]+ '[' 0 -ne 1 ']'
[stderr]+ nvm_echo 'Now using node v16.15.0 (npm v8.5.5)'
[stderr]+ command printf '%s\n' 'Now using node v16.15.0 (npm v8.5.5)'
[stdout]Now using node v16.15.0 (npm v8.5.5)
[stderr]+ EXIT_CODE=0
[stderr]+ set -e
[stderr]+ return 0
[stderr]+ npm ci
[stdout]
[stdout]added 183 packages, and audited 184 packages in 1s
[stdout]
[stdout]16 packages are looking for funding
[stdout] run `npm fund` for details
[stdout]
[stdout]1 critical severity vulnerability
[stdout]
[stdout]To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
[stdout] npm audit fix --force
[stdout]
[stdout]Run `npm audit` for details.
[stderr]+ npm start
[stdout]
[stdout]> web@0.0.1 start
[stdout]> node server.js
[stdout]
[stderr]node:events:505
[stderr] throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[stderr] ^
[stderr]
[stderr]Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
[stderr] at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1372:16)
[stderr] at listenInCluster (node:net:1420:12)
[stderr] at Server.listen (node:net:1508:7)
[stderr] at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/Web/server.js:47:8)
[stderr] at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
[stderr] at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
[stderr] at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
[stderr] at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
[stderr] at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
[stderr] at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
[stderr]Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
[stderr] at emitErrorNT (node:net:1399:8)
[stderr] at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
[stderr] code: 'EADDRINUSE',
[stderr] errno: -98,
[stderr] syscall: 'listen',
[stderr] address: '::',
[stderr] port: 3000
[stderr]}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change port number in your project or you can kill 3000 port at EC2 instance :).